# Howto use non-static member function for template argument?

Tags: c++, templates

I have this minimal sample code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


template<class ReadFileCallback>
void fileMgr_ReadWithCallback(std::string filename, ReadFileCallback callback) {
    callback("OK");
}

void globalReadResult(std::string result) {
    std::cout << "ReadResult in global function: result=" << result << std::endl;
}

class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass() {};
  ~MyClass() {};
  
  void Read() {
    fileMgr_ReadWithCallback("file", globalReadResult);
    //fileMgr_ReadWithCallback("file", this->ReadResult);
  }
  
  void ReadResult(std::string result) {
    std::cout << "ReadResult in member function: result=" << result << std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass c;
    c.Read();
    
    return 0;
}
```

For callback function I'd like to use a non-static class member `MyClass::ReadResult`. It would also be good to know before calling the callback if the object is still valid (non-destructed), because otherwise the program will fail I guess.

How shall I change this code to be able to use the `MyClass` object's `ReadResult` as callback?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just wrap it into a lambda:

```
class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass() {};
  ~MyClass() {};
  
  void Read() {
    fileMgr_ReadWithCallback("file", [this](const std::string& result){ this->ReadResult(result); });
  }
  
  void ReadResult(std::string result) {
    std::cout << "ReadResult in member function: result=" << result << std::endl;
  }
};
```

Comment: `ReadResult` expects one argument. You are trying to call it with none.

Comment: Small remark, it is important that the object `MyClass c;` does not go out of scope before the callback is invoked.

Comment: Is there any other way (with changing the template itself for example)?

Comment: @pptaszni, as this is constructed, `fileMgr_ReadWithCallback` is called within the context of the class object. `MyClass c` cannot go out of scope (we have to be able to call `Read` on the object).

Comment: @Daniel, not by keeping the argument list as it is. You would need to pass the object for the member as well. Each non-static member function needs `this` as an argument (it's implicitly the first argument). That's why the lambda is handy - it captures the this-object and passes it "under the hood".

Comment: @Daniel, here is how you could do it: https://godbolt.org/z/feeMK6 (but I do not recommend it, the syntax is not so nice).

Comment: Thanks looks what I was looking for. If I store the callback function for calling it later, and `MyClass` instance goes out of scope before calling it, how can I check for this huge source of UB?

Comment: @Daniel: If you need to own the callback and want to have the flexibility to store different types (functors and function pointers), it's probably easiest to use `std::function`. Then you can store all types that are callable and call them later. You can remove the template and have `std::function<void(const std::string)>` as the parameter instead.

Comment: I'd keep the template because I also need other stuff, but I'm storing the callback like this: `stored_func = [=](std::string s) { (object->*callback)(s); };`. But I have a fear that if `c` goes out of scope, `object` also goes out of scope, so when I call this as `stored_func("somestring");` it will use an invalid `object`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use std::bind.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>


template<class ReadFileCallback>
void fileMgr_ReadWithCallback(std::string filename, ReadFileCallback callback) {
    callback("OK");
}

void globalReadResult(std::string result) {
    std::cout << "ReadResult in global function: result=" << result << std::endl;
}

class MyClass {
    public:
        MyClass() {};
        ~MyClass() {};

        void Read() {

            using std::placeholders::_1;
            //std::function<void(std::string)> func = std::bind( &MyClass::ReadResult, this, _1);
            auto func = std::bind( &MyClass::ReadResult, this, _1);
            

            fileMgr_ReadWithCallback("file", func);

            //
            // or
            // fileMgr_ReadWithCallback("file", std::bind( &MyClass::ReadResult, this, _1));
        }  

        void ReadResult(std::string result) {
            std::cout << "ReadResult in member function: result=" << result << std::endl;
        }  
};

int main()
{
    MyClass c; 
    c.Read();


    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: There's no reason to use `std::function` here.  The object returned by `std::bind` is itself a function object.  You could just use `auto` type deduction or put the `std::bind` call directly in the `fileMgr_ReadWithCallback` call.

Comment: Yes using std::bind directly is better. But I usualy choose more detailed case to help reader understand the code better.

Comment: `auto func = std::bind(...); fileMgr_ReadWithCallback("file", func);` is still expressive but avoids the runtime overhead of `std::function`.  In general, `std::function` is best reserved for when you actually need its type erasure capabilities.

Comment: If you are blessed with c++20, you can use `std::bind_front` instead and skip the placeholders.